# Magento 2 Facebook Product Feed script in CSV format

Tags: magento2, facebook

I am looking for script to run on Magento root which will dynamically generate csv file for facebook product feed.

if anyone have generated script please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can helpful this extension for dynamically generate product feed csv for facebook.

https://marketplace.magento.com/apptrian-facebook-pixel.html